# linearization of differential equations question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, linearization

Consider $\frac{d\psi}{dt}=cos(\psi)$.

Linearizing $\psi$ about $\frac{\pi}{2}$ by setting $\psi= \frac{\pi}{2}+\phi$ , where $\phi$ is very small, we obtain $\frac{d\psi}{dt}=\frac{d\phi}{dt}=-sin \phi$ . Since $\phi$ is very small, $\frac{d\phi}{dt}=-\phi$. Hence the general solution is $\phi= Ae^{-t}$.

Question:

Using $\phi$ , approximate
the time it takes for $\psi$ to change from $\psi=\frac{1}{3}$ to $\psi=1$.

My idea consisted of setting $\psi(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}+Ae^{-t}$ and then getting the $t_1$ such that $\psi=1$ and $t_2$ such that $\psi=\frac{1}{3}$ then subtract $t_1-t_2$.

Would this be correct?

Comment: Recall that you do not know "A"

Comment: @Snifkes  so $t_1-t_2$ will be expressed in terms of $A$... right?

Comment: With ODEs you generally have to provide an initial condition in order to find a proper solution. That is, you must be certain of the time at which one of the states is happening. so you have to impose $t_1$, for example.

Comment: These values are so far away from the expansion point that I would at least take the next term $ϕ'=-ϕ+\frac16ϕ^3$ and solve this as Bernoulli equation, $ϕ(t)^{-2}-\frac16=(ϕ(0)^{-2}-\frac16)e^{2t}$ etc.

Comment: @Snifkes Okay, but the question hasn't specified initial conditions. An earlier problem said If $\psi(0)=\frac{1}{3}$ then find the time it takes for $\psi=1$. So my questions are: (1) Should I consider the initial condition $\psi(0)=\frac{1}{3}$? (2) What if no initial conditions has been specific, should I just find the expression $t_1-t_2$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann we haven't discussed bernoulli yet

Comment: You get $A$ uniquely from $ψ(t_1)=\fracπ2+Ae^{−t_1}$ after you have fixed some value for $t_1$. As that is arbitrary, you could as well take $t_1=0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann so my answer would simply be $t_2$, after I find $A$? But I don't see why we have to impose initial conditions

Comment: To answer this, define $A(t_1)$ and $t_2(t_1)$ as functions of $t_1$, see whether the expression $t_2(t_1)-t_1$ depends on $t_1$. Otherwise, you can define $A(t_2)$ and $t_1(t_2)$ as functions of $t_2$ and see whether the expression $t_2-t_1$ depends on $t_2$

Comment: Of course you could also just simply use $\frac{ψ_1-\fracπ2}{ψ_2-\fracπ2}=e^{t_2-t_2}$ which has no parameter and only depends on the time difference.

Comment: @LutzLehmann alright, but is it mandatory to impose initial conditions? note that an earlier part of the problem has said: find t if $\psi(0)=\frac{1}{3}$ for $\psi=1$.

Comment: @Snifkes so my approach $t_2-t_1$ is indeed the correct one?

Comment: @orientablesurface I guess your initial approach is correct as well, just that traditionally we use initial conditions (it simplifies the problem quicker). The fact the you impose initial conditions to your ODE does not affect $t_2-t_1$ because your ODE does not involve functions in $t$ explicitely.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d\psi}{dt}=cos(\psi)$$

Without initial condition :

Let $\psi(t)=\tan^{-1}(2y(t))$

$$\frac{d\psi}{dt}=\frac{2}{4y^2+1}\frac{dy}{dt}\quad\text{and}\quad \cos(\psi)=\cos(\tan^{-1}(2y))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4y^2+1}}$$
$$\frac{dt}{dy}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4y^2+1}}$$
$$t=\int \frac{2}{\sqrt{4y^2+1}}dy=\sinh^{-1}(2y)+c$$
$$y=\frac12\sinh(t-c)$$
$$\psi(t)=\tan^{-1}(\sinh(t-c))$$